# Install Ubuntu alongside Windows in UEFI

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning, grub2, uefi

I want to install Linux alongside Windows and my Device is UEFI and I have GPT disk , I want to install it manually to create swap and home partition and I already have EFI partition by Windows so should I mount it to `/boot/efi` or install Linux without editing it? and if I should edit it , after that if I decided to uninstall Linux? Should I cancel the mount of the EFI partition or Leave it as it was?

Because some people mount it and some people install it without doing this step.

Another thing what should I choose in device for bootloader installation?

Comment: I read that you have only one disk, so only one EFI partition, so no games needed to override the installer putting the bootloader there.  You don't need to change the bootloader install location, and even if you tried, the first EFI will be used regardless of what you enter.

Comment: You do not need swap if installing 20.04 as it now uses a swap file. Make / just a bit larger. You have to use Something Else install option to create or use a /home partition separate from / (root).  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI
Shows Windows screens
https://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-10-with-uefi

Comment: So I don't need to choose any location it will install in the efi partition but what about the bios devices as they don't have efi partition and I still want to know should I mount the windows efi partition

Answer (score 0):

there is many tutorials are exist in internet, but ill teach you one:

1.First Resize Your Windows Partition and leave (at least 20GB) Unmodified
Disk Space.

2. Insert Ubuntu ISO Image, flash driver or etc.. to Boot into Ubuntu Installation
3. Follow Installation Instructions (everywhere in internet) But In Installation Location You Should Select The Unmodified Space and create a partition then format it to ext4, after choose that partition you created then start installing it.
4. after ubuntu installation was complete you should run this command in terminal (it makes the windows selection available in next boot):

Try One of those:

```
$ update-grub

$ update-grub2
```

Comment: I know all this things I want to know if I should monut the windows efi partition ?!

Comment: @Yousief You are not forced to do it. you can leave the partition unmounted, and then after ubuntu installed, mounting it manually using mount command (based on the disk device in /dev/), it was a external partition and its not been one of the linux parts, so i suggest you leave the ntfs partition unmounted.

Comment: I don't speak about if I mount it during installition or later I speak about if it is a nesscery for booting and I must do it

Comment: @Yousief its not necessary . you can mount it everytime!

Comment: It's fat32 instead of ntfs. And you didn't answer the question.